# XDebug PHP with Sublime Text 3 - Debuging not working - Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug my php with sublime text and I got some permission denied problems.

I did all installation and the phpinfo() says xdebug is working perfect.

My project.settings config is this one:

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
      "follow_symlinks": true,
      "path": "C:/Development/GitHub/portaleducacional"
    }
  ],
  "settings":
  {
      "xdebug": {
        "path_mapping": {
        "educacional.localhost/" : "C:/Development/GitHub/portaleducacional/",
        },
      "url": "http://educacional.localhost/",
      "super_globals": true,
      "close_on_stop": true
      }
   }
}
```

---

My xdebug.settings default:

```
{
  "path_mapping": {
    "educacional.localhost/" : "C:/Development/GitHub/portaleducacional/",
  },
  "url": "http://educacional.localhost/index.php",
  "ide_key": "sublime.xdebug",
  "port": 9000,
  "super_globals": true,
  "max_children": 32,
  "max_data": 1024,
  "max_depth": 1,
  "break_on_exception": [
  "Fatal error",
  "Catchable fatal error",
  "Parse error",
  "Notice",
  "Strict standards",
  "Deprecated",
  "Xdebug",
  "Unknown error"
  ],
  "close_on_stop": false,
  "hide_password": false,
  "pretty_output": false,
  "launch_browser": false,
  "browser_no_execute": false,
  "disable_layout": false,
  "debug_layout" : {
    "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
    "rows": [0.0, 0.7, 1.0],
    "cells": [[0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]]
  },
  "breakpoint_group": 2,
  "breakpoint_index": 1,
  "context_group": 1,
  "context_index": 0,
  "stack_group": 2,
  "stack_index": 0,
  "watch_group": 1,
  "watch_index": 1,
  "breakpoint_enabled": "circle",
  "breakpoint_disabled": "dot",
  "breakpoint_current": "",
  "current_line": "bookmark",
  "python_path" : "",
  "debug": false
}
```

---

my php.ini config on xammp:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.6-5.5-vc11.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

---

And finaly what I got is this:

( ! ) Warning: include_once(C:\Development\GitHub\portaleducacional): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Development\GitHub\portaleducacional\index.php on line 130Call Stack#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation10.0000156112{main}( )..\index.php:0

( ! ) Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Development\GitHub\portaleducacional\index.php on line 130Call Stack#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation10.0000156112{main}( )..\index.php:0

---

Permission denied when I try the adress with the debug ( http://educacional.localhost/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug )

And I have XDebug Extension installed on Chrome and without the xdebug on the adress (just http://educacional.localhost/ and with xdebug extension enabled) nothing happens, the site load normaly but no debug. I already did the config in XDebug Extension, I put the IDKey in "Other" and put the sublime.xdebug.

Any Ideas how to solve this? I did something wrong?

Tnx a lot